# Cascade delete in Fluent NHibernate using Composite ID on a HasMany Relationship with Integrity constraint

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-cascade

I have an error, and no matter how much I Google it I cannot find a fix for it.
I have read and tried to solve it using the following topics.  These are the closest I've found related to my issue:

- [Fluent NHibernate and Collections Mapping](http://marekblotny.blogspot.com/2009/02/fluent-nhbernate-and-collections.html)
- [How to cascade Save with CompositeId in NHibernate?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nhusers/7M-MI8RLalg/discussion)
- [How to map an objectified Many to Many relationship?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nhusers/OwyWQrsqTqc/discussion)

### DB Schema

Four tables are involved in my mapping: `Member`, `Vehicle`, `MemberVehicles` and `LastUsedVehicles`.

- Tables `Member` and `Vehicle` are business objects in the application.
- Table `MemberVehicles` is an association table (`many-to-many`) with no extra columns.  This relationship works with no issues.
- Table `LastUsedVehicles` has a composite key consisting of
  `Vehicle_uid` and `Member_uid`, which are foreign keys to those corresponding tables.  The table also has an extra `DateLastUsed` column to store the timestamp.  **The mapping of this
  table is my issue.**

### The Problem

When I delete a `Member`, I need all of his `Vehicle`s to also be deleted (this works fine - the records are deleted from the many-to-many table), as well as all of the associated `LastUsedVehicles` records (this is the part that does not work).

When I execute this code...

```
    try
    {
        using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            Member member = nHibernateMemberRepository.GetMemberBySomeMethod(x,y)
            if (member != null)
            {
                if (nHibernateMemberRepository.Delete(unitOfWork, member))
                {
                    unitOfWork.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

... I receive this error:

> System.Exception : Attempt to commit during UnitOfWork failed;
>   transaction was rolled back due to the following error: The given key
>   was not present in the dictionary.   ---->
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : The given key was
>   not present in the dictionary.

I do not receive an error when the `LastUsedVehicles` table is empty.

### Mappings

#### Member

```
public class MemberMap : ClassMap<Member>
{
    public MemberMap()
    {
        Table("member");

        HasManyToMany<Vehicle>(x => x.Vehicles) // working fine
            .Table("member_vehicles")
            .ParentKeyColumn("MEMBER_UID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("VEHICLE_UID")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

        HasMany(x => x.LastUsedVehicleses)
            //.Table("LASTUSED_VEHICLES")
            .KeyColumn("MEMBER_UID")
            .Fetch.Select()
            //.KeyColumns.Add("VEHICLE_UID")
            //.KeyColumns.Add("MEMBER_UID")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

#### Vehicle

```
    public class VehicleMap : ClassMap<Vehicle>
    {
        public VehicleMap()
        {
            Table("vehicles");

            HasManyToMany(x => x.Members) // working fine
                .Table("member_vehicles")
                .ParentKeyColumn("VEHICLE_UID")
                .ChildKeyColumn("MEMBER_UID")
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate();

            HasMany(x => x.LastUsedVehicles)
                .KeyColumn("VEHICLE_UID")
                .Inverse()
                .Fetch.Select()
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

        }
    }
```

#### LastUsedVehicle

```
    public class LastUsedVehiclesMap : ClassMap<LastUsedVehicles>
    {
        public LastUsedVehiclesMap()
        {
            Table("lastused_vehicles");

            CompositeId()
                .KeyReference(x => x.Vehicle, "VEHICLE_UID")
                .KeyReference(x => x.Member, "MEMBER_UID");

            Map(x => x.DateLastUsed)
                .Column("DATELASTUSED")
                .Not.Nullable();

            // Things that I tried
            //References(x => x.Member)
            //    .Fetch.Select()
            //    .Cascade.None()
            //    .Column("MEMBER_UID");
            //
            //References(x => x.Vehicle)
            //    .Fetch.Select()
            //    .Cascade.None()
            //    .Column("VEHICLE_UID");

            //Version(x => x.DateLastUsed)
            //    .Column("DATELASTUSED")
            //    .Not.Nullable();

        }
    }
```

### Classes

#### Member

```
public class Member : PrimaryKeyBase
{
    private readonly Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Vehicle> _vehicles;
    private Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<LastUsedVehicles> _lastUsedVehicles;

    public Member()
    {
        _vehicles = new HashedSet<Vehicle>();
        _lastUsedVehicles = new HashedSet<LastUsedVehicles>();
    }

    // ... GetHashCode ...

    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Vehicle> Vehicles
    {
        get { return _vehicles; }
    }

    public virtual void AddVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        vehicle.AddMember(this);
        _vehicles.Add(vehicle);
    }

    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<LastUsedVehicles> LastUsedVehicleses
    {
        get { return _lastUsedVehicles; }
        set { _lastUsedVehicles = value; }
    }
}
```

#### Vehicle

```
public class Vehicle : PrimaryKeyBase
{
    private Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Member> _members;
    private Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<LastUsedVehicles> _lastUsedVehicles;

    public Vehicle()
    {
        _members = new HashedSet<Member>();
        _lastUsedVehicles = new HashedSet<LastUsedVehicles>();
    }

    public virtual Member Member
    {
        get { return _members.FirstOrDefault(); }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Member> Members
    {
        get { return _members; }
    }

    public virtual void AddMember(Member member)
    {
        _members.Add(member);
    }

    public virtual void AddLastUsedVehicle(LastUsedVehicles lastUsedVehicles)
    {
        lastUsedVehicles.Vehicle = this;
        lastUsedVehicles.Member = this.Member;
        _lastUsedVehicles.Add(lastUsedVehicles);
    }

    public virtual void ClearLastUsedVehicles()
    {
        _lastUsedVehicles.Clear();
    }

    public virtual LastUsedVehicles LastUsedVehicle
    {
        get { return _lastUsedVehicles.FirstOrDefault(); }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<LastUsedVehicles> LastUsedVehicles
    {
        get { return _lastUsedVehicles; }
    }
}
```

#### LastUsedVehicles

```
    public class LastUsedVehicles : CompositeKeyBase
    {
        public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime DateLastUsed { get; set; }

        public virtual bool Equals(LastUsedVehicles other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
            return Equals(other.Vehicle, Vehicle) && Equals(other.Member, Member);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != typeof(LastUsedVehicles)) return false;
            return Equals((LastUsedVehicles)obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return ((Vehicle != null ? Vehicle.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397)
                    ^ Member.GetHashCode()
                    ^ DateLastUsed.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

    }
```

### Debugging Info

To make it clearer, I'm also attaching some SQL queries and their results.

```
// Delete a member
delete from member m where account = 'X'; // FAIL - Child record found - The member has vehicles - So makes sense

// Delete all vehicles from a member from vehicles table
delete from vehicles mv where mv.vehicle_uid =
(select mv.vehicle_uid from member_vehicles mv where member_uid = (
select mm.member_uid from member mm where account = 'X')); //

// Delete all vehicles from a member from association table
delete from member_vehicles mv where member_uid = (
select mm.member_uid from member mm where account = 'X');

// Delete data on LASTUSED_VEHICLES - works
delete from LASTUSED_VEHICLES lv
where lv.vehicle_uid =
  (select mv.vehicle_uid from membervehicles mv where member_uid = (
          select mm.member_uid from member mm where account = 'X'));
```

Once the table `LASTUSED_VEHICLES` is empty, I can delete a member.

---

Sorry for the length of the post but this scenario seems to be quite unique. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: It's been a while since you posted this so I don't know if you still care about this question, but if so, I have a few questions of my own.  Does `LastUsedVehicles` record the last vehicle a member used, or does it record the last time a member used each vehicle?  The difference would be in whether `LastUsedVehicles.Member_uid` should have a unique constraint on it or not.  Based on your mappings and the DB schema, it sounds like it's "last time a member used each vehicle", but based on the name of the table, it sounds like "last vehicle a member used".